# How can i write a picture to a nfc tag in android

Tags: android, uri, nfc

According to NFC Forum, in the SmartPoster Record specification there is a Icon record, that can be added to the URI record. ( http://www.maintag.fr/fichiers/pdf-fr/nfcforum-smartposter-rtd-1-0.pdf ). I have no idea how to write it, yet create a application to write SmartPoster Records with Icon Records. Anyone has any idea how to write these?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Android stack supports this functionality, if you look at the SmartPoster.java example given by Google it only contains the Title, Action, Type and URI and doesn't include the Size or Icon records.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/record/SmartPoster.html